# webpack build website without routed components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I made react-app and webpack from scratch, and everything works and looks fine in webpack-dev-server. But when I build (bundle) app to file it not showing components from 'Route' path.

Webpack outputting no errors so I don't know how to fix that. This is the project: https://github.com/kamilmoskal/react-movies-library-app

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were trying to open index.html as regular file in the browser. The application should be deployed on some server.

The easiest way to  make it work is to serve it on you local machine using i.e. [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve):

1. `npm install serve --save`
2. `cd doc`
3. `serve`

Then navigate to `http://localhost:5000` in your browser

Comment: Yes i was trying open regular file in browser, but it shouldn't work? i thought that webpack convert dynamic app to static so i can normally open it throught index.html without any server

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out the problem was with < Route exact path='/' ...  when path is like this "/",  to fix that i changed:

```
  from:  import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
  to:    import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

  and in code below from: <BrowserRouter>
                          ...
                          </BrowserRouter>

                      to: <Router> 
                          ...
                          </Router>
```

When i was doing apps throught standard 'npx create-react-app my-app' it was enough to add < BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}> but in this case it didint work. maybe it will help someone.